# bisection root finding segmentation fault

Tags: c, floating-point, segmentation-fault, floating-point-precision, bisection

I use following code to find roots of functions using a simple bisection algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef float (*continous_function)(float);

static const float epsilon = 0.0000001;

#if __STDC__
static __inline float fabsf(float x)
{
        return x >=0 ? x : -1*x;
}
#else
#include <math.h>
#endif

float poly_1(float x)
{
        return x*x*x+2*x*x+3;
}

float poly_2(float x)
{
        return 2*x + 3;
}

float poly_3(float x)
{
        return 5*x*x*x*x*x+3*x*x*x+2*x+7;
}

static __inline void swap_in_place(float *a, float *b)
{
        float tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
}

float bisection_root(continous_function f, float a, float b)
{

        float neg = f(a);
        float pos = f(b);
        float c = 0.5 * (a + b);
        float mid;

        if (neg * pos > 0) {
                /* neg and pos should have different sizes */
                abort();
        }

        if (neg > 0) {
                /* Ensure f(a)=neg is negative */
                swap_in_place(&neg, &pos);
                swap_in_place(&a, &b);
        }

        mid = f(c);

        if (fabsf(mid) < epsilon) {
                return c;
        } else {
                if (mid > 0)
                        return bisection_root(f, a, c);
                else
                        return bisection_root(f, c, b);
        }

}

int main()
{
        {
                float a = -5;
                float b = 2;
                printf("Root of x^3+2*x^2+3 is %f\n", bisection_root(poly_1,a,b));
        }

        {
                float a = -2;
                float b = 0;
                printf("Root of 2*x+3 is %f\n", bisection_root(poly_2,a,b));
        }

        {
                float a = -1;
                float b = 0;
                printf("Root of 5*x^5+3*x^3+2*x+7 is %f\n", bisection_root(poly_3,a,b));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This program cause segmentation fault when compiled on windows xp (32-bit) using mingw gcc.

When the number of decimal digits of `epsilon` decreased, segmentation fault can be avoided. Therefore, I conclude that segmentation fault have something to do with an overflow.

I would like to know why and how exactly this error occurs so that I can find a reliable way to set epsilon or fix other errors that might cause the problem.

Comment: Did you try with a debugger?

Comment: Floats don't segfault. Recursing too often *can* segfault. Why isn't that a loop anyway?

Comment: writing hardcoded float numbers have certain criteria.  1) they contain a decimal point.  2) they have a trailing 'f'   It is obvious that the problem is mainly that the recursion depth is greater than the available stack space. can handle.  perhaps placing a (temporary) printf in the top of the recursive function would clarify the problem to you.

Comment: You can have `mid == a` or `mid == b`, which will cause you to recurse indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static const float epsilon = 0.0000001;
```

There does not need to be a float for which the value of your polynomial is at distance `epsilon` from 0. In particular if the root is for largish values of `x`, the polynomial may jump from being less than `-epsilon` to being more than `+epsilon` between one float and its successor.

In this case, and in many others, your algorithm will loop, Since you implemented it with recursion and C compilers usually do not guarantee tail-call optimization, this infinite loop can result in a segmentation fault (when the stack becomes full).

The solution, applicable whether you use recursion or a simple `while` loop, is to limit the number of iterations.

Note: you should read about [Horner's scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) for computing polynomials.